# How to call a Javascript function in an attribute of an element

Tags: javascript, php, promise

I'm working in laravel php and have blade.php views,

I have the following component which is used in blade.php as follows

```
<x-form.select
            wire:model.defer="state.trip_destination"
            :search="true"
            x-search="
                (query) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve(fun()); //HERE
                    });
                }
            "
            name="state.trip_destination"
            type="text"
            id="trip-destination"
        />
```

Now I want to call the function fun() which is just returning a string, and is defined as

```
<script>
function fun()
{
    return "HELEL";
    debugger;
};
</script>
```

It doesn't goes to that function because it is out of scope, is there any way to solve this problem.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean "out of scope"? As you have presented it, `fun` is in the global scope, so it cannot be out of scope.

Comment: It says, "reference error, fun is not defined"

Comment: I don't know how `x-search` is evaluated. Is that a blade thing? If so, then tag your function with the appropriate tags, so you get the experts in that field here.

Comment: It is input field, just changed how it's named

Comment: You should add the relevant tags, to highlight which framework is ensuring that the `x-search` value is evaluated as JavaScript code.

Comment: Try look at this link: https://newbedev.com/laravel-right-way-to-import-javascript-into-blade-templates   Let me know if it works